# combining user input variables into one variable. One of which may not be a variable

Tags: python, variables, passwords, generator

I am making a password generator. How do I make it that if the user enters **no** to the questions. no uppercase, for example. The generator sill works just without the uppercase?

```
   print("hello, Welcome to Password Generator")
            length = int(input('Please enter the length of password: '))
            upperanswer = input("Would you like to use UpperCase? ")
            if upperanswer == "yes":
                    upper = string.ascii_uppercase
            loweranswer = input("Would you like to use LowerCase?")
            if loweranswer == "yes":
                    lower = string.ascii_lowercase
            numberanswer = input("Would you like to use Numbers?")
            if numberanswer == "yes":
                    numbers = string.digits
            specialanswer = input("Would you like to use Special Characters?")
            if specialanswer == "yes":
                    special = string.punctuation
            all = lower + upper + numbers + special
            temp = random.sample(all,length)
            password = "".join(temp)
            print(password)
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with this code is that if you answer anything but `yes` to `upper` the variable will be undefined. I would recommend extending a string which i've called `characters`, this way you can refer to it no matter what the user answers.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import string
import random
print("hello, Welcome to Password Generator")

characters = ""

length = int(input('Please enter the length of password: '))
upperanswer = input("Would you like to use UpperCase? ")
if upperanswer == "yes":
        characters += string.ascii_uppercase
loweranswer = input("Would you like to use LowerCase? ")
if loweranswer == "yes":
        characters += string.ascii_lowercase
numberanswer = input("Would you like to use Numbers? ")
if numberanswer == "yes":
        characters += string.digits
specialanswer = input("Would you like to use Special Characters? ")
if specialanswer == "yes":
        characters += string.punctuation

temp = random.sample(characters, length)
password = "".join(temp)
print(password)
```

result:

```
hello, Welcome to Password Generator
Please enter the length of password: 10
Would you like to use UpperCase? no
Would you like to use LowerCase? yes
Would you like to use Numbers? no
Would you like to use Special Characters? yes
%-injo!&^e
```

Comment: Thanks so so much Zhenhir! My assignment due tommorow!

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the strings empty when the user enters no, by adding an `else` statement to each `if` statement see code below. Note that this will of course fail if the user tries to enter no for all of the options, as then no characters will be available

```
import random
import string

print("hello, Welcome to Password Generator")
length = int(input('Please enter the length of password: '))
upperanswer = input("Would you like to use UpperCase? ")
if upperanswer == "yes":
    upper = string.ascii_uppercase
else:
    upper = ""
loweranswer = input("Would you like to use LowerCase?")
if loweranswer == "yes":
    lower = string.ascii_lowercase
else:
    lower = ""
numberanswer = input("Would you like to use Numbers?")
if numberanswer == "yes":
    numbers = string.digits
else:
    numbers = ""
specialanswer = input("Would you like to use Special Characters?")
if specialanswer == "yes":
    special = string.punctuation
else:
    specialanswer = ""
all = lower + upper + numbers + special
temp = random.sample(all, length)
password = "".join(temp)
print(password)
```

Comment: ... Or set them to empty strings in the beginning so it won't need the `else` clauses.

Comment: Thanks so so much Ewan Brown and Zhenhir! My assignment due tommorow!